# popen2 not outputting to octave

Tags: c#, octave

It appears popen2() is not outputting the Console.WriteLine( contents to Octave.
When the code is executed with popen() (slightly modified so does not expect input ofc) output to octave works as expected.
Other example code using popen2 works with output. My suspicion is that the C# code is messing with the output stream?

Do you have any ideas what could be causing this?

Octave code:

```
[in, out, pid] = popen2("XY Demo.exe");
for i=1:35
fputs(in, "10.00 10.00\n");
fgets(out)
pause(1);
endfor
fclose (in);
fclose (out);
```

This is using https://github.com/Triamec/XYDemo(C#) with slight modifications in the MoveAxis() section:
(ultimate goal is to be able to send position commands via octave to the servo drives)

```
       async Task MoveAxis() {  
            string octave_data;
(...............................)
                while (true) {
                        //get input
                        octave_data = Console.ReadLine();
                        //acknowledge input
                        Console.WriteLine("1\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                        //convert input to string and double
                        string[] octave_data_single = octave_data.Split(' ', '\t'); //format: '000.000 000.000'
                        double x_comm = Convert.ToDouble(octave_data_single[0]);
                        double y_comm = Convert.ToDouble(octave_data_single[1]);
                        //feed respective input to drives
                        var xReq = _xAxis.MoveAbsolute(x_comm);
                        var yReq = _yAxis.MoveAbsolute(y_comm);
                        await yReq.WaitForSuccessAsync(moveTimeout);
                        await xReq.WaitForSuccessAsync(moveTimeout);
                        //return a ok value when at position
                        Console.WriteLine("2\n");
                }
(.............................)
        }
```

Comment: The program reads one line, then writes two. Your Octave script writes one line, then reads one line, then wants to write another line. This is I think where the process halts, with Octave wanting to write and the program also wanting to write.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i get -1 as feedback inside Octave nomatter how much i send from the c# code. Also tried without sending from Octave to C# (an no waiting for input in c#). The C# --> Octave pipe is broken somehow.